# Problem counting repeating elements without taking into account the same array position

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to count the repeating elements of an array, but not taking into account the repeating elements in the same position of the array.

For example I have the following array:

```
let array = ['a','data country name data', 'day data day', 'service name data','a'];
```

And when trying to count:

```
console.log(array.reduce((a,d)=>(a[d] ? a[d] += 1:a[d]=1, a),{}))
```

The result shows me:

```
a: 2
data country name data: 1
day data day: 1
service name data: 1
```

The output it should show is:

```
a: 2
data: 3
country: 1
name: 2
day: 1
service: 1
```

Comment: You'll need to split the strings and iterate the resulting array inside the reduce()

Comment: use an object, key value pairs

Comment: @Nur Isn't OP already using an object in the reduce() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) first to split each element if it includes multiple words:

```js
const array = ['a','data country name data', 'day data day', 'service name data','a'];

const occurences = array
.flatMap(str => [...new Set(str.split(/\s+/))])
.reduce((a,d) => (a[d] ? a[d] += 1 : a[d] = 1, a), {});

console.log(occurences);
```

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your answer but I should not count those that are in the same position of the array. As I describe in the question. For example: the word 'data' will only count 3 and not 4.

Comment: @Emily yes I updated the answer 3 min ago

Answer (score 0):

You could count the unique words of the strings.

```js
const
    array = ['a', 'data country name data', 'day data day', 'service name data', 'a'],
    counts = array.reduce((r, s) => {
        new Set(s.split(/\s+/)).forEach(w => r[w] = (r[w] || 0) + 1);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(counts);
```

Comment: right, but data occurs only three times of the strings ...

Answer (score 0):

1. `.join()` the array into a single string, then `.split()` the string into an array and convert that into a `Set` of unique values

   ```
   {"a", "data", "country", "name", "day", "service"}
   ```
2. Convert `Set` into an array `[...Set]` then `.map()` it as an array of zero value pairs.

   ```
   [["a", 0], ["data", 0], ["country", 0], ["name", 0], ["day", 0], ["service", 0]]
   ```
3. Then convert the previous result to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`.

   ```
   { "a": 0, "data": 0, "country": 0, "name": 0, "day": 0, "service": 0 }
   ```
4. Go back to the original input array and `.split()` each string into another array of sub-strings then remove any repeating strings by converting sub-strings into a `Set` then back into an array.

   ```
   ['a', 'data country name', 'day data', 'service name data', 'a']
   ```
5. Finally, tally the occurrence of each string to the object from step #3. Repeat this for each string of the original input array.

   ```
   { "a": 2, "data": 3, "country": 1, "name": 2, "day": 1, "service": 1 }
   ```

```js
let array = ['a', 'data country name data', 'day data day', 'service name data', 'a'];

const wordCount = arrayOfStrings => {
  const AS = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrayOfStrings));
  let SET = new Set(AS.join(' ').split(' '));
  let pairs = [...SET].map(key => [key, 0]);
  let words = Object.fromEntries(pairs);
  for (const string of AS) {
    let sub = new Set(string.split(' '));
    [...sub].forEach(word => words[word] += 1);
  }
  return words;
};

console.log(wordCount(array));
```

Comment: Your output does not match what OP wants, specifically `data` should be 3, not 4, because only 3 entries contain the word "data".